# Is there any misunderstanding about the onActivityCreated fragment callback?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-lifecycle

`onActivityCreated` seems to mean "This fragment callback is executed just after the activity has been... created... I mean, just after the fragment is correctly attached to the activity. There, you can safely call `getActivity`, it won't return null, except if the activity is `null` for some special reason".

However, I've seen that the fragment callback `onAttach` is called even after `OnCreate`, it means that the fragment has been attached to the activity, which has been created.

The complete workflow for a fragment (and for a fragment dialog, which is frequently left behind) is: `onAttach` -> `onCreate` -> `onCreateView` -> `onActivityCreated`. So in each of these 4 methods (perhaps not `onAttach` I don't know), the activity is normally not null and attached to the fragment.

So my question is: why does the callback `onActivityCreated` since the activity is, in fact, already created and attached to the fragment 3 callbacks ago???

Comment: What does "quiproco" mean? I'm not familiar with that term.

Comment: @MikeM. Hi , it means "misunderstanding"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically in onAttach() we get confirmation is that activity is attached to my fragment, I can use getActivity() to fetch things like resources like

```
getActivity().getResources.getDrawable(R.drawable.abc)
```

but Suppose if You want to fetch the views inflated in activity's xml like If you want to access

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Myelement)
```

You might get null here, so OnActivtyCreated() ensures that activity's view is inflated, You can access activity's views now (Activity's view has been created (onActivityCreated))